# Task 'install' not found in root project

Tags: maven, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Task 'intall' not found in root project 'JDA-Paginator'.
- Try:

> Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Getting this error while running gradle install. My Gradle File

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

    implementation("net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.0-alpha.5") {
        exclude module: 'opus-java'
    }
}
```